# How to go for an interview on my last day?

Tags: interviewing, quitting

I am quitting from my current job without another job lined up. But I have attended few interviews this month and I have been told today by one of them to come for second interview which is with their boss. Unfortunately it has been scheduled on my last day and I cannot take any leave. I also have to be there at the end of the day for last day formalities. To add to that I have a last day lunch with my team.

I asked for change of date and they said they cannot do it since their boss schedule is very busy. I am thinking to tell the current employer the situation and to ask for 2 hours time off in the day, but I don't know how it will workout.

**How can I go to this interview?**

Comment: If it's your last day, you're not showing up for a couple of hours is tough. What are they going to do, fire you?

Comment: @MeredithPoor but burning bridges and leaving on bad terms can be detrimental to ones career. you never know if you will have to interact with them again, perhaps as clients, perhaps as colleagues or a boss in a new job if they move too.

Comment: @RhysW - This taking time off to go interview for another job isn't particularly malicious.  Were I in the situation of the present manager, I would congratulate him on finding another opportunity and grant him leave to meet with his new employer.  If he did it without telling me in advance, I'd forgive him.  There are worse things departing employees could do.

Comment: @MeredithPoor your second comment suggests telling him in advance and organising it with him, which i find acceptable, your original comment that i disagreed with seemed to suggest just ditching work for a couple of hours without agreed permission from your current company

Comment: @RhysW Agreed..A 'I don't care what you say as its my last day attitude' would not be a smart move...they are providing a lunch as well so everything still seems in good nature.

Comment: You're either leaving on good terms or you're not. If needing to leave a little early on you final day is a bridge burner, you've done something wrong or your employer is just the bitter type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As they already know you are leaving and presumably know that you are looking for other work just be honest and say that you need the day off for an interview and that you're willing to forfeit that day's pay if need be. After all you may need a reference from them if you get the job.

On a side note, this possible employer has no other time then your last day at work?

I'd be a bit worried about that, what happens if you get the job and you need to speak to your manager and he/she has "no other time". Surely they can rearrange it somehow, like what would happen if you are sick on the day of the interview?

Comment: Consider getting the reference before you leave.

Comment: There is a big difference between "no other time" for a face to face interview and "no other time" to answer a phone call or reply to an EMail.  If the boss is going on vacation or will be travelling on business for a period of time, this may be the only day he is in the office.  That does not imply that he his un-available to respond to you as an employee in that same time window.

Answer (score 2):

You can go about this a few different ways

1.) Ask your new potential employer if there is any possible way you can do it another time, like the day after what is already scheduled or later in the day. Explain to them the situation you are having and that you need to be there for last day formalities.  If they are/want to be a successful employer then they would understand and I'm sure they would want the same from one of their employees if they were leaving.  If they think that their time is the most valuable and you should drop everything for them then I would remember that and consider that later on when deciding to take a job there.  By choosing this option I think the company you are interviewing with would see it as showing your **loyalty** and that is a valuable asset in employees that is hard to come by.

2.) Ask your current/old employer there is a different way to go about your last days.  You could come in on the last day and have lunch and say your goodbyes and such and then leave for your interview.  And then come in the next day to do the formalities with HR and your boss.  You could probably say goodbyes then instead as well.  First explain the situation and I'm sure your current employer could work something out.  I don't think you will be "*burning any bridges*".  And if you do "*burn bridges*" by being professional and explaining the situation and asking in a professional way then you're probably right to leave that company and they will probably only burn more bridges themselves until they are on an island and I don't think that will hurt you.  You can explain that to any employer later on if that ever comes up and I'm sure they would understand

**Best Option:** I think the best option here, and best of both worlds, would be to try and do formalities in the morning and have lunch with your team and then leave after lunch to go to your interview. Or if your interview is in the morning, go to your interview and then come back for lunch and finish formalities in the afternoon.  That way there is a compromise.  Both sides should understand.

Comment: The OP said that they would not be able to change the interview as the boss has a busy schedule.

Comment: I know, but like I said if they want to be successful they should be able to make time.  And if you read my post some of my other suggestions don't even involve the boss changing his schedule.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey: And other options are likely to be useful to future readers of this question.